# Can I get the locations in my vector of vectors to each point to each of their neighbors?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, nodes

Edit: My goal is to be able to find the escape path of a maze of characters that is in a text file and will be inputted through cin. So, I created a vector of vectors of characters to hold this maze map. My next step is to find the escape path from the starting point to the end point using either stack or queue.

For example: The map might be

```
# * #
* * D
S * #
```

where # are walls, * are open spaces to walk on, S is the start, and D is the end.
The solution to output would then be: ENEE.

To do this, I want to have each location in the matrix point to its neighbors so that if I am at a certain location, I can access the characters stored in the locations north, south, east, and west of the current location.

What is the best way of going about this? Should I have generated my matrix differently, or can I add the pointers separately?

Here is what I have for the vector of vectors:

```
vector<vector<char>> GetMap(int& M, int& N)
{
    vector<vector<char>> matrix{}; 
    char char_buf;

    for (int rows = 0; rows < M; rows++)
    {
        matrix.push_back(vector<char>()); 
        for (int cols = 0; cols < N; cols++)
        {
            cin >> char_buf; 
            matrix.back().push_back(char_buf);
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}
```

Comment: First of all if you plan to change this matrix size (add new elements) having pointers or iterators to neighbors is not a good idea - they could be invalidated.

Comment: You say "but I realized afterwards that I will be needing to have each location in my vector of vectors to point to each of its neighbors".    That is as clear as mud.

Comment: It looks like [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please describe problem your code should solve (X), before you describe your problem with your solution (Y).

Comment: Apologies for not being very clear. I edited my description. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you mean if you have a vector like:

```
vector<vector<char>> matrix = {{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
                               {'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'},
                               {'I', 'J', 'K', 'L'},
                               {'M', 'N', 'O', 'P'}};
```

And an index, say [2, 2] ('K'), you want to be able to navigate "North" (to 'G'), South (to 'O'), East (to 'L'), or West (to 'J').

There's no need for pointers here, we can actually accomplish this with some simple arithmetic!

Here's an example I've mocked up where you have some coordinates of the form [x, y] and a `dir` in [N, S, E, W]:

```
switch(dir) {
    case 'N':
    case 'n':
        y = (y - 1) % matrix.size();
        break;
    case 'S':
    case 's':
        y = (y + 1) % matrix.size();
        break;
    case 'E':
    case 'e':
        x = (x + 1) % matrix[y].size();
        break;
    case 'W':
    case 'w':
        x = (x - 1) % matrix[y].size();
        break;
}
```

See it in action here: [ideone](https://ideone.com/LO5eUg)

Comment: I'm sorry, I realized that I wasn't very clear in my explanation of what I was trying to do, so I edited my description above. Thank you for your input though!

Comment: @ashe_lam even with your edit, I believe this still applies. You don't need pointers. If you have a location's indexes, you can use math to calculate the index for the values that are N/S/E/W. See my example on ideone for more on what this is doing.